# MVC4 razor accessing JsonResult data from my model in client side javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonresult

I am working on an MVC4 razor project. I have a list of role objects that I store on my model as a jsonResult intended to be used in my client-side javascript.

```
//Model
public JsonResult JsonRoles { get; set; }

//Controller
var myroles = from r in myroles select new { r.Id, r.Description };
var myModel.JsonRoles = Json(myroles);


//Client side javascript
var data = '@(Model.JsonRoles)';
alert(data);
```

I tried to access this in javascript as below. When I alert I always get the string "System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult" but what I need is the json data.
What am I doing wrong? Can someone please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used ViewData to solve your problem and im able to get the result  on the similar lines you can resolve model property also

```
//Contoller Class 
 public ActionResult CreateRequest()
        {

            var data = new { Id = "one", Make = "Two" };


            ViewData["Data"] = Json(data);

            return View();

        }

//And client side is 

  <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Data"]));
        alert(JSON.stringify(data.Data));
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay. This solved my problem. I had tried Json.Encode and Html.Raw but not both together.

Comment: Good answer, saved me a lot of trouble. However this didn´t work for me unless I used explicit expression @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Stuff))); but maybe that´s due to some other aspects of my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In linqpad, I was able to get the data back out via

```
var x= new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult();
x.Data=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("testing, testing");
x.Data.Dump();
```

also checked with

```
var x= new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult();
x.Data=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new{test="testing"});
x.Data.Dump();
```

Which may not be the correct solution for in a razor page. I expect

```
var data = "@{Model.JsonRoles.ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);}";
```

to be correct in a proper mvc app.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonResult` tends to be used as the return type of an action method you intend on calling from Ajax.

You need to use the `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize your "myroles" object.  E.g.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
myModel.JsonRoles = serializer.Serialize(myroles);
```

Change the type of JsonRoles on your model to string.

```
public string JsonRoles { get; set; }
```

Finally, output in your view as e.g.:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Model.JsonRoles);
alert(data.id);
```

Comment: HI Tony. Thanks for the answer. I had already attempted this but I was getting escape characters in Json making it invalid. I could remove the escape characters but I was trying to get a better solution that would not require me to do this elsewhere in my project. I went with Ajay's answer below as it got around this problem.